# Is "person p is sitting immediately to the right of the person q" a function?

Tags: functions, relations

This is the simple exercise I am trying to solve, where I have to say if $R$ is a function, but I would like to have some feedback on my solution:

> John, Mary, Susan, and Fred go out to dinner and sit at a round table.
>   Let $P = \{John, Mary, Susan, Fred \}$, and let $R = \{ (p,q) \in P
>  \times P \mid$ the person p is sitting immediately to the right of the
>   person q $\}$. Is $R$ a function from $P$ to $P$?

I think this is a function, because if they are sitting in a round table, each person $p$ in the group has just 1 person $q$ to its left.

I know this is a simple simple problem, but just to make sure I am not studying wrongly.

Comment: Your thinking is correct. In fact it is a bijective function on $P$.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, what if one of those sitting at the table is facing away from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is perfect. In fact, it's not too hard to show that this function is also injective (one-to-one) and surjective (onto). Since the domain is equal to the codomain, we say that $R$ is a special type of bijection known as a **permutation**.

Comment: In general, if a function $f$ maps from a set $A$ to a set $B$, then we say that $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $B$ is the codomain of $f$. For $R$, the domain and codomain are both $P$. So I mean that $R$ maps the set of all people to itself.